# Failed to complete official Tutorial from Discord documentation

Tags: discord, discord-interactions

I followed discord tutorial to create a bot. https://discord.com/developers/docs/getting-started#running-your-app .

I can't get slash command to work. (/test and /channel)
From logs in glitch IDE, I get the following error.

```
403
Error: {"message":"Missing Access","code":50001}
at DiscordRequest (file:///app/utils.js:34:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async HasGuildCommand (file:///app/commands.js:16:17)
```

The line that cause error is line 16. shown below.

```
// Checks for a command
async function HasGuildCommand(appId, guildId, command) {
  // API endpoint to get and post guild commands
  const endpoint = `applications/${appId}/guilds/${guildId}/commands`;

  try {
    const res = await DiscordRequest(endpoint, { method: 'GET' });
    const data = await res.json();
    ...
```

So this tells me that either appID or guildID are incorrect, but I don't think it is.

I followed every step correctly according to the tutorial to get all my credentials.

is it a common problem?

what is the best place to get help related to discord.js implementation problem?

reddit?

submit ticket to discord support? (seem sooooooooo over kill)

does discord have discord server to ask this question? I found discord-tester, discord-deverloper. To join, I need to takes quizzes or whatever. I will just do this last if reddit and submitting ticket doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: It is possible that your bot is in a server in which it may not have permissions to create slash commands.

Answer (score 0):

discord developers >  OAuth2 >  General

- check applications.commands

discord developers >  OAuth2 > URL Generator

- check applications.commands

[discord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq72N.png)